# Parse.com cloud code dirty relation

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using Parse Cloud code hooks (beforeSave).
My object has a relation and I need to know which objects where added to this relation.
My problem is exactly the same than [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/running-code-beforeafter-save-for-relation).
I want to be able to do this :

```
var op = myObject.op('toto');

//Get all add op in relation toto
var added = op.added();

//Get all remove op in relation toto
var deleted = op.removed();

added.forEach(function(pointer) {
     //Do something with pointer

     //If you need value on pointer
     pointer.fetch(function(objectFetched) {
         //Do something with object
     });
});
}
```

But that is not working anymore because

> Result: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'added'

How can I do now to know which objects was added to the relation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no information on this in Parse documentation. I had to poke through their source code to figure out how to do the exact thing for my Cloud Code. Anyway, you can get an **Array** of objectIds that are being added to a *Relation* like this:

```
var added = request.object.op("toto").relationsToAdd;
```

If you want to find the ones being removed, just replace `relationsToAdd` with `relationsToRemove`

Comment: Thank you  a lot !